# Oracle - Hint CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT is not working in 'Select Case' statements

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I am using **cursor_sharing='FORCE'**
This can be set by SYSTEM user executing following statement:
*alter system set cursor_sharing='FORCE' scope=both;*

For few queries I want to use the hint CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT, but it is failing in CASE statements.

For example, Query1 works, but same query with hint CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT (Query2) fails.

**Please suggest why there is a missing expression**
**Note:** I cannot put the CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT on the outer SELECT where it works.

**Query1:**

> SELECT CASE
>       WHEN (select 1 from dual where 1 = 2) IS NOT NULL
>       THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END temp FROM dual;

**Output of Query1:** N

**Query2:**

> SELECT CASE
>       WHEN (select /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ 1 from dual where 1 = 2) IS NOT NULL
>       THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END temp FROM dual;

**Output(Error) of Query2:**

> ```
> Error starting at line 1 in command:  
> SELECT CASE  
> WHEN (select /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ 1 from dual where 1 = 2) IS NOT NULL  
> THEN  'Y' ELSE 'N' END temp FROM dual  
> Error at Command Line:2 Column:7  
> Error report:  
> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
> ```
>
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in 11.2.0.4 (Solaris), 12.1.0.2 (Solaris), or 12.2.0.1 (Windows).  What version and platform are you running on?

Comment: Oracle Version: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Woops, I wasn't using `alter system set cursor_sharing='FORCE' `.  Once I changed that value (and ran `alter system flush shared_pool`) I could reproduce it on every system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I put the `HINT` on the parent query and now it's ok, try to do so:

```
SELECT /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ 
  CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ 1 from dual where 1 = 2) IS NOT NULL
      THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' 
 END temp 
FROM dual;
```

2) OR as a temporary solution maybe you can use `decode` instaed of `case`:

```
SELECT DECODE ((select /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ 1 from dual where 1 = 2), NULL, 'N', 'Y') FROM dual;
```

3) Also another Alternative solution is:

```
  WITH demo AS (
   SELECT /*+ CURSOR_SHARING_EXACT */ <col1> from <table_name> 
      where <some_conditions>)
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN d.col1 IS NOT NULL
              THEN 'Y' 
                ELSE 'N' 
            END temp 
    FROM dual, demo d;
```

Comment: When the script is run using cursor_sharing=EXACT, the plan is cached.
So after changing the cursor_sharing back to FORCE, change the query a little (change 1=2 to 11=22), and it will fail.

Comment: If the Hint is added to outer select, it works(as mentioned in the question), but I cannot put it there due to some restriction.